# how to resize the mobile screen to show optimised UI web app version?

Tags: css, mobile, bootstrap-4, sass, media-queries

I am using react, Bootstrap,and some custom sass to build and style my front end web app, the design looks good on mobile but you need to pinch the screen(it looks zoomed in a little) to adjust to the screen width properly,
how can I configure the media query properly to fix this?
the screenshots(before fingers adjustment and after) will explain more!

before adjustment with fingers
[image]
after adjustment with fingers
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been resolved, if you ever encountered a similar problem where a screen zoomed-in on mobile try this meta line by posting it on your HTML `head` tag!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,  initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;user-scalable=0;"/>
```